# Raking with strata using R survey package

Tags: r, survey, poststratification

I have a survey design with 12 strata and have the marginal distributions of the post-stratification variables for each stratum.  I am calling the rake function in the `survey` package as follows:

```
the_design = svydesign(ids=~SID, strata=~Stratum, weights=~Baseweight, data=my_data)

raked_design = rake(design=the_design , sample.margins=list(~Stratum+Annual_Income), population.margins = list(income_frequencies))
```

However this code produces the following error:

```
Error in postStratify.survey.design(design, strata[[i]], population.margins[[i]],  : 
  Stratifying variables don't match
```

I believe this is telling me that I need to change `income_frequencies` which is a data.frame that looks like this:

```
   HHI_lt75K HHI_gt75K
0   7.116883 11.038961
1   4.218109 10.173087
2  17.362333 10.796333
3   6.333889  9.296901
...
```

and where row.names='Stratum' for this data.frame.

Unfortunately I do not know

1. If this truly is what the error message is telling me, and
2. If this is what the error message is telling me, what I need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the [`rake`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/4.0/topics/rake) function indicates that "The sample.margins should be in a format suitable for `postStratify`".

The Details section of the [`postStratify`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/4.0/topics/postStratify) documentation indicates that "the population totals can be specified as a table with the strata variables in the margins, or as a data frame where one column lists frequencies and the other columns list the unique combinations of strata variables".

After I created `income_frequencies` as the following `data.frame` :

```
Stratum Annual_Income   Frequency
0       HHI_lt75k       7.116883
0       HHI_gt75k       11.038961
1       HHI_lt75k       4.218109
1       HHI_gt75k       10.173087
2       HHI_lt75k       17.362333
2       HHI_gt75k       10.796333
3       HHI_lt75k       6.333889
3       HHI_gt75k       9.296901
...
```

the code worked just fine.